# How to change magic 8 ball answer when phone is flipped?

Tags: java, android, accelerometer, android-sensors

I need to create a magic 8 ball app that will change the answer when the phone is flipped. Hence when the z value of android accelerometer is less than 9 I need the answer to change once.

My problem is that since the accelerometer values keep changing when the phone is held at a stable position within the values of the if statement the loop will just keep executing.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
    private float xvalue, yvalue, zvalue;

    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor accelerometer;

    private float z;


    TextView answer;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

        sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        zvalue = sensorEvent.values[2];

        if(zvalue > 9 & zvalue < 9)
            printAnswer();

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {}

    /** Called when the user taps the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        printAnswer();

    }

    public void printAnswer(){
        answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);
        final String[] answers = {"It is certain", "It is decidedly so", "Without a doubt", "Yes definitely", "You may rely on it", "As I see it yes", "Most likely", "Outlook good", "Yes",
                "Signs point to yes",  "Reply hazy try again", "Ask again later", "Better not tell you now", "Cannot predict now", "Concentrate and ask again",
                "Don't count on it", "My reply is no", "My sources say no", "Outlook not so good", "Very doubtful"};

        Random r = new Random();
        int randomNum = r.nextInt(answers.length);

        answer.setText(answers[randomNum]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `z` actually being set somewhere? It should be as simple as keeping track of the last value and only calling `printAnswer()` when the new value crosses the threshold.

Comment: @JakeHolzinger sorry just edited it now

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of different ways to make this happen. Both of the ways I'll mention here are in the category of "debouncing" which is the process of smoothing over rough input.

You could keep a `prevZ` variable that always gets set at the end of `onSensorChanged`. This will help you know how `z` changes over time. If `prevZ` is less than your threshold and current `z` is above it, you've just identified a flip! If both Zs are below your threshold or above your threshold then do nothing. In this case it might be better to have 2 thresholds: a higher threshold to initialize a flip and a lower threshold for when to indicate that the flip is over. Otherwise weird scenarios might jump back and forth around your threshold and you'll still be in this situation.

Probably a better approach is to keep a timestamp of the last time you noticed a flip. When a new flip occurs, check how long it's been since the last flip. If you're within 1 second of the last flip, do nothing. More than a second? Flip again and update the timestamp for last flip. You can play around with the 1 second gap until you find a delay that's long enough that you don't display a fortune too often, but short enough that people don't feel gypped that their flip wasn't recognized (e.g. 10 seconds is probably too long).

Comment: how would i go about indicating that the flip is over?

Comment: When prevZ is above the threshold and current z is below it.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to compare the `z` value from the last event and the current event and only call `printAnswer()` when crossing the threshold. Second, you're using a bitwise operator (`&`) you should be using a logical operator (`&&`).

```
long lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    float newZ = sensorEvent.values[2];
    long newTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // Only print the answer when the device is flipped down
    // and there wasn't an answer for at least 1 second.
    long timeDiff = (newTime - lastTime) / 1000.0; // seconds
    if (zvalue > 9 && newZ < 9 && timeDiff > 1)
        printAnswer();

    zvalue = newZ;
    lastTime = newTime;
}
```

Comment: The problem is when the device goes further than 9 it changes and when it comes back lower than 9 it changes again.

Comment: Simply remove one of the threshold checks, then it will only work when crossing the threshold in one direction.

Comment: this works when the device is flipped at a normal speed. However when i flip the device really slowly there are times when the answer changes twice

Comment: You could add an additional check to see if there was a recent answer, but that would add additional side effects like preventing a new answer if the device is flipped back-and-forth multiple times very quickly (which is likely what is happening when slowly flipping the device, the accelerometer isn't perfect).